# FFMpeg Speed up transparent webm C#/Cmd

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, webm

I am trying to speed up a webm video file while maintaining the transparency but every attempt I've made has removed the transparency.

How do I speed up a transparent webm using FFMpeg without losing the transparency?

Note: I am doing this all in c# but would prefer to use commands instead of wrapper libraries.

this is the general command I have tried:

`command = $"-i \"{input}\" -filter_complex \"[0:v]setpts = (1/{speed}) * PTS[v]; [0:a]atempo = {speed}[a]\" -map \"[v]\" -map \"[a]\" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 1M -y \"{output}";`
That command did not maintain transparency though.

A little info about the input video:

- The input is transparent
- the input is basically a mess of individual transparent webm's joined together that were made with either:

  - Poster with audio:

`$"-threads 4 -loop 1 -i \"{image}\" -i \"{audio}\" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuva420p -crf 10 -b:v 0 -c:a libopus -b:a 192k -shortest -movflags +faststart -y \"{output}\"";`

- Padding the clip:

`$"-i \"{input}\" -filter_complex \"[0:v]split=2[v1][v2];[v1]tpad=start_duration={startPadMs / 1000}:start_mode=clone:stop_duration={endPadMs / 1000}:stop_mode=clone[v1_edited];[v1_edited][v2]overlay=eof_action=pass[v];[0:a]adelay={startPadMs}|{startPadMs}[a]\" -map \"[v]\" -map \"[a]\" \"{output}\""`

- Joining videos:

`var temp = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "concat.txt"); File.WriteAllText(temp, string.Join('\n', clips.Select(e => $"file '{e}'"))); var command = $"-f concat -safe 0 -i "{temp}" -c copy -y "{output}"";\`

Comment: Try adding `-pix_fmt yuva420p` after `libvpx-vp9`.